# Add a settings page looking like in native app

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.forms

I would like to create settings page which would look like the settings on native platform (eg. PreferenceActivity/Fragment with xml on Android).

I am used to design the settings page by creating simple preference xml on Android which handles the basic settings flawlessly, however I am unable to find the similar mechanism in Xamarin.Forms which would do the same thing for all platforms natively (with the gui part). I just only found the SettingsPlugin which handles "Create and access settings from shared code across all of your apps!".

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

I would really appreciate any recommendation on designing the settings pages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [TableView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview), which is an original Xamarin Forms User interface (without any plugin).
If you set his `Intent="Settings"` , you can display a nice list of configuration settings like SwitchCell, EntryCell, or a CustomCell.

Displaying these elements depend on the operating system and on the version of it. So it looks and feels different on f.e. Android 4.4 and different on Android 8.

For example:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="My settings">
            <EntryCell Label="Name:" Placeholder="Enter Your First Name Here"/>
            <SwitchCell Text="Show my name" On="true"/>
            <SwitchCell Text="Update app automatically"/>
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

Which will render something (not exactly that) like this: [{source of img}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That fits my needs :-)

Comment: Can you get it that it saves these settings automatically ?

Comment: @rogue39nin save where? if you mean as app setting use Preferences. Its easy and simple. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android

Comment: Yes but i was wanting it to appear in the actually settings coag of andriod @Martinedo

Comment: How can I change the heading of the settings?

Comment: @Hacki which heading do you mean?

Comment: The "settings" one, the one that is on the top

Comment: @Hacki the heading comes from the title of the content page, within the ContentPage header set the Title to what you need.