# How to create a setting in an Xamarin Android App that is configurable via App Wrapping

Tags: android, xamarin.android, application-settings

I have created a Xamarin Android App that has a single setting that the user is prompted to enter on first start-up.  The setting is then saved using `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set` and retrieved from then on using `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get`.

I need to make this setting configurable via "App Wrapping".  I have search high and low to work out how to do this, and I am not able to find an example.

I did want to create the setting in a way where it showed in the Android Settings app (Android Settings/Apps/App Setting for the app), thinking if the setting was accessible in there it would be configurable by App Wrapping, but was not able to find a way of doing this either.

My app doesn't have a settings UI and doesn't need one, I just need a way to make this one setting configurable via App Wrapping.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I am using the following environment:

- IDE: VS2019
- Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab Active Pro
- Android: 9
- Packages:

  - `Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils`
  - `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design`
  - `Xamarin.Android.Support.Supportv4`
  - `Xamarin.Essentials`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Let me clear this, you're looking to read some Android settings and based on that set your app settings or you want to "create" an Android setting ?

Comment: @FabriBertani, so the app has one value, a URL that needs to be configured.  I just wanted to make that a setting that showed in the Android OS Settings app (Android Settings/Apps/App Setting for the app), as I thought that this would then be configurable by an App Wrapping layer.  I could not find a way to make my setting show up in the Android OS Settings app.  My app does not need a setting UI, just the ability to be configured with the URL by App Wrapping.  Is that making sense?

Comment: I don't think you could just add an OS setting from your app. You must handle that setting within your application.

Comment: @FabriBertani ok fair enough.  So how can a setting inside the application, as I have done with Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set, be configurable by AppWrapping?

Comment: @ScottyLaughton Hi, you'd better detail the needed option of setting in question. Then we can check whether it's possible to achieve that totally. In addition, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850763/add-a-settings-page-looking-like-in-native-app) may be helpful, you could have a look.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found no evidence that in Android you can add a custom setting to the Android Settings app (Android Settings/Apps/App Setting for the app).
Instead I have opted to save a file with my setting value to `Xamarin.Essentials.AppDataDirectory`, and this way App Wrapping can be used to pre-configure config value they want in the file.  If the file is not there when the app starts then I prompt the user for the value on first start-up and write it there.  So it can either be pre-configured via App Wrapping or the user can enter it.